# How to convert string access token to AccessToken object in Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-insights

I found my page access token by using the graph api. Now i would like to use my page access token and look up insights for that page. Problem is the page access token returned by the graph api is just a string not a AccessToken object.

I have looked everywhere and could not find anything about converting the found page access token string into a AccessToken object. Is there anyway to take the found page access token string and use it with the Graph api?

Function used to find page access token

```
public void getPageAccessToken(Context context, final Callback callback)
{

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    pageId = prefs.getString("CurrentPageID","nullValues");
    Log.d("viewmodel",pageId);


    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            accessToken,
            "/"+ pageId+"?fields=access_token" ,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    // Insert your code here

                    Log.d("viewmodel",""+response.getRawResponse());
                    try {
                        pageAccessToken = response.getJSONObject().getString("access_token");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("viewmodel"," " + pageAccessToken);
                    callback.findPageAccessCallback(pageAccessToken);
                }
            });

    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the object yourself using the String:

```
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(TOKEN_STRING, APPLICATION_ID, USER_ID, null, null, null, null, null)
```

Except for the first 3 parameters, rest can be null and will be updated when refreshed.
On documentation, parameters are listed:

> AccessToken(String, String, String, Collection, Collection, AccessTokenSource, Date, Date)

[image]

Comment: You are welcome, I remember trying to find this back when I was new to programming but never found the answer, so seeing your question was kinda nostalgic haha